# Backup directory using cmd with windows scheduler

Tags: cmd, backup, windows-task-scheduler

How can I make a batch file to backup a directory on windows scheduler to automatically update on a specified time everyday e.g 6 pm and save the directory with the directory name along with the date and time the backup was made.

I have searched a particular command for backup using cmd.

```
backup d:\Assignment\*.* d:\backup  /s
```

but it is not recognized as any internal or external command.
the directory structure is.

- source: d:\Assignment
- Destination: d:\backup\

Comment: `backup` is not part of the windows-cmd built in commands. Do you use an external utility?

Comment: No I didn't use any but i found this on variety of web places. but if its not then what is the solution of the particular problem?

Comment: either use a external backup solution or (as it looks like you are not really want to do a real backup, just "rescue" your files to another directory) use `copy` or `xcopy`. I'd suggest `xcopy` because it has a lot of useful parameters (see `xcopy /?`).

Answer (score 1):

This should work in Vista and higher - it uses Robocopy (don't call it robocopy.bat).

Be very careful when specifying the target directory because the `/mir` option will create a mirror copy and `delete files` that don't exist in the source tree.

**The `/mir` switch will wipe a drive if the root directory is specified as the target.**

```
The first four lines of this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher.

@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"

robocopy "d:\Assignment" "d:\backup\Assignment %fullstamp%"  /mir
```

It just remains for you to test this and set it up in Task Scheduler.

Comment: thanks but didn't work for me but found another solution. Thanks

Comment: If you open the cmd window and type the batch file name then you will see any error messages on the console.  I notice now that you are creating backups on the same drive, but if the drive fails then `ALL` your backups will disappear too.  Back them up to different media - and have two separate copies of those backups on different media.  DVD/CD/USB stick/External drive etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
:: variables
set drive=d:\Backup
set folderdate=%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y
echo ### Backing up My Documents...
%backupcmd% "d:\Assignment\*.*" "%drive%\Assignment\%folderdate%"
echo Backup Complete!
echo Backup Complete - Your Backup is located at %drive%
@pause
```

It worked for me.